# Filtragem especifica com MySql

Tags: mysql, query

Olá, amigos.

Tenho um banco de dados mysql,

e estou fazendo algumas consultas

Quero saber como eu posso fazer uma filtragem bem especifica.

Por exemplo, tenho um banco de dados:

```
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
| callId | callDay    | callTime | disposition |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
|      7 | 2020-12-18 | 08:00:00 | ANSWERED    |
|      8 | 2020-12-18 | 08:00:00 | NO ANSWER   |
|      9 | 2020-12-18 | 08:00:00 | BUSY        |
|     10 | 2020-12-18 | 09:00:00 | ANSWERED    |
|     11 | 2020-12-18 | 09:00:00 | NO ANSWER   |
|     12 | 2020-12-18 | 09:00:00 | BUSY        |
|     13 | 2020-12-18 | 10:00:00 | ANSWERED    |
|     14 | 2020-12-18 | 10:00:00 | NO ANSWER   |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

No caso desse banco de exemplo, eu quero recolher todos os registros, mas quero quero omitir os valores repetidos dentro da coluna "callTime", ou imprimir apenas os registros da "callTime" em que há mais campos de acordo com a coluna "disposition", isso é possivel?

```
Gostaria que saída fosse mais ou menos assim:
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
| callId | callDay    | callTime | disposition |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
|      7 | 2020-12-18 | 08:00:00 | ANSWERED    |
|      8 | 2020-12-18 |          | NO ANSWER   |
|      9 | 2020-12-18 |          | BUSY        |
|     10 | 2020-12-18 | 09:00:00 | ANSWERED    |
|     11 | 2020-12-18 |          | NO ANSWER   |
|     12 | 2020-12-18 |          | BUSY        |
|     13 | 2020-12-18 |          | ANSWERED    |
|     14 | 2020-12-18 | 10:00:00 | NO ANSWER   |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo da saída esperada?

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta, mas, agora que tô vendo melhor, acho que o que tô tentando fazer é meio idiota. Mesmo assim, seria possivel fazer?